# Rails show views for PaperTrail versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, versions, paper-trail-gem

I have quite an odd usecase for PaperTrail. In my scenario a version is based on a physical event happening. Due to this, versions of my model are only created when I say.

Because of the above. I wish those versions to be capable of the following things:

When I run something like `Model.all`, this should ignore versions as expected but in some cases I wish versions to be returned as normal so I need to be able to do something like `Model.withVersions` to be returned all the current records and all associated versions. Is this possible?

Also, I need to be able to build a page for versions. Ie: Rails Show Action and View.

How would I accomplish this? I need to be able to craft a link to one of the pages that would output something similar to `/model/23` which would take you to a page about a particular version of that item.

I know this is sort of an odd issue but wondering if anyone would have any input on this strange usecase and how I can sometimes bring versions to the foreground to act like existing things and othertimes to stay in the background as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what we're doing here is using the fact that PaperTrail adds a new method to your model called `versions` which returns an array of `PaperTrail::Version` objects, one for each version of the model. On any of those version objects you can call `.reify` to get the model at that version.

Now, I'm not sure how you'd want those versions to be returned, so let's say we create an array of versions for each model and store them in a hash keyed by the primary keys of each model:

```
hash = {}
Model.all.each { |m| hash[m.id] = m.versions.map(&:reify) }

# so to see the array of all versions of model with id=1
hash[1]
```

Re your show page, you will need to pass the version as a parameter, eg. `/model/23?version=5` and then in your `show` action you'll do something like:

```
@model = Model.find(params[:id])
if params[:version]
  @model = @model.versions[params[:version]-1].reify
end
```

Comment: That's very very helpful. I might try to add a member route to my model resource to integrate versions into the URL fully if one exists.

Comment: Say I wish to Search my Model but want to return results including all versions. Currently I use searchkick and run `Model.search()`. I take it I would have to reify all versions before hand and somehow get them added to the index. Hmm, confusing stuff!

Comment: @rctneil - y'know, here on StackOverflow, there's another way to indicate that an answer has been really helpful.

Comment: Absolutely. I was not intending to leave it unaccepted. I apologise.

Comment: Related q: I have a page which `reify`'s a models version and outputs that using a partial I made for that model. That partial then includes a rails link_to path helper like `model_path(model)`. The link that is output from this links to the latest version and not the reified one. Sorry that's rather confusing. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how searchkick works, but yeah, I'd guess you'd have to do what you said. As I mentioned in the second part of your question above, you'd need to include the version in that path helper, like `model_path( model, version: model.version)`